# How to convert uint8[] to string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, client-server, uint

Hi
I am doing work on an iPhone application
I am getting some response of server in my buffer with data type Uint8
now i want to Match my buffer with a string, can any body tell me how can i check it? a piece of code is given

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type,  CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{

    CFDataRef df = (CFDataRef) data;
    int len = CFDataGetLength(df);
    if(len <= 0) return;

    CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0,len);
    UInt8 buffer[len];
    NSLog(@"Received %d bytes from socket %d\n", 
          len, CFSocketGetNative(s));
    CFDataGetBytes(df, range, buffer);
    NSLog(@"Client received: %s\n", buffer); 

    NSLog(@"As UInt8 coding: %@", df);
    [mTextViewAlias setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: buffer]];
    ////////////.............////////////
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *search = @"ACPT";

    NSRange match;

    match = [buffer rangeOfString: search];

    if (match.location == NSNotFound)
        NSLog (@"Invalid Username Or Password");
    else
    {
        [lvc goToWatchList];

        NSLog (@"match found at index %i", match.location);
    }
}
```

any body have some idea?
i'll be very thankful

Comment: Under this line "match = [buffer rangeOfString: search];" here comes a warning "invalid receiver type 'Uint8[1]'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response may be `UInt8` but you don't need to copy it into a `UInt8[]` as your already have it in a `CFDataRef` (assuming the `void *` you pass in really is a `CFDataRef`, if it isn't you have other problems...) - a `CFDataRef` is toll-free bridged with `NSData` (i.e. you can just cast from one to the other), and you can construct an `NSString` directly from the bytes in an `NSData`. Your code, removing the logging and adding direct NSString conversion:

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type,  CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *buffer = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)data
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSRange match = [buffer rangeOfString:@"ACPT"];
    [buffer release];

    if (match.location == NSNotFound)
        NSLog (@"Invalid Username Or Password");
    else
        [lvc goToWatchList];
}
```

Alternatively as, at least in your sample code: are not saving the converted buffer, are using a literal string for the search, and your use of `%s` implies the data is null-terminated; you could do all this directly with C functions without creating intermediate objects:

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type,  CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

    char *buffer = (char *)CFDataGetBytePtr((CFDataRef)data);

    if (strstr(buffer, "ACPT") == NULL)
        NSLog (@"Invalid Username Or Password");
    else
        [lvc goToWatchList];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]
    initWithData:(id)data
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: hmmm some thing like this
infect i want to assign the data in my Uint8 array to a string but i am not getting it

Comment: Since you already have the data as `NSData` in the `data` variable, why don’t you create the string from that?

Comment: Ahhh wow how stupid i am why i was not looking at data lolzzzz
thank u so much Zoul :) i got it

Answer (score 0):

The warning appears because `rangeOfString` is a method of `NSString` and `buffer` is not an `NSString`. I think it would be better if you could convert the data into NSString. I think it will work if you try using `stringWithData:`

**UPDATE**

Pls check this [Link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/205860-how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-nsstring.html)

Comment: thanx for reply, can u plz give me some detail that how to convert uint8 into a string? how to use StringWithData:?